# Application of binomial probability to sequence matches

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I'm searching for the number of matches of a three nucleotide sequence (GTG) in a window of 9 nucleotides located at a certain position in a large number of DNA fragments. I want to answer the question: What is the probability of seeing results as high as the results I'm seeing.

Based on empirical computation (using 1 million random 9 nucleotide sequences), I get a proportion r (=.1044) for 1 or more pattern matches of the 3 nucleotides across these randomly generated windows. Failure is 0 matches, success is 1 or more matches.

I want to use this proportion r in order to produce a null distribution from which I can determine a p value for the number of matches I find experimentally across a large number of actual DNA fragments (a ChIP-seq library, if anyone is interested).

So for example, I get 9896 positive outcomes (1 or more matches in the defined 9 bp window) across 62084 tested fragments.

In R, why can I not use a binomial distribution to determine the p value as `1 - pbinom(9895,62084, .1044)`, i.e, the probability of seeing 9896 or more positive outcomes based on the null distribution?

I think I'm making some conceptual error, but I can't figure out what it is.

Update:
The reason I thought I had a problem is that the p value was changing with the number of trials.  I can now see why this is mathematically necessary from the distribution function.  Is there an alternative approach whereby I can escape this dependence of p value or data likelihood on the number of fragments I am investigating.  I am running this test on a number of ChIP-seq datasets with different library sizes, and having the result depend on size is not ideal.  I could sub-sample, but changing the p value by altering the library size *ad hoc* is unbecoming.

Comment: The answer depends on the sequence itself.  See our thread on [string matches](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=string+match) for details.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I realize that it does depend on the sequence.  I used the specific sequence GTG in order to get the parameter for the null distribution.  I don't think that the problem I'm having relates to sequence-dependence, but I may not be fully understanding your comment.

Comment: Since the chance depends on the sequence but your `pbinom` formula does not, it cannot be correct.

Comment: But l'm only interested in finding the specific sequence GTG among a variable set of 9-mers.  There is a clear probability of finding vs not finding that can be calculated for GTG w.r.t. 9-mer sequences of random bases.  Would you mind giving me a more detailed account of my conceptual error?  I'd appreciate it, because I'm really struggling to see it.

Comment: For intuition, simplify the problem: *e.g.* compute the chance of HH in a random word of length 3 from the alphabet {H,T}. There are 8 possible words, each with a 1/8 chance. Three of them contain HH: HHH, HHT, THH, making that chance equal to 3/8. But the chance of HT is 4/8 because HHT, HTH, THT, and HTT all contain HT. Notice there are four occurrences of HH, but because it appears in *two* overlapping places in HHH, it occurs in fewer words than HT (which cannot overlap with itself).  The pattern of possible "self-overlaps" determines the answer.

Comment: Yes, I know all that. This is how I calculated the probability for GTG in a 9-mer: samples = replicate(1000000, paste0(sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), 9, replace = T), collapse = "")); 
counts = sapply(samples, function(x) stri_count_fixed(x,"GCG")); 
sum(counts > 0)/1000000.  
I have that probability.  I'm wondering what to do once I have that probability.  My p value varies with the number of fragments tested, as described in the update I added to the main question.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand the vague "what to do" question.  If you want to compute the chance by brute force, note that there are only $4^9=2^{18},$ about a quarter million, possibilities, implying you can enumerate them all in less time than your simulation requires and thereby obtaining the exact answer.